# What happens if input voltage to switching regulator is outside of its specifications?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply

A switching regulator e.g buck, boost e.t.c requires that the input voltage be in a certain range. Then, it shall use feedback to generate the required output voltage. Fair enough.

What will happen if the input voltage is above the required input voltage range or below the required input voltage range?

The question is asking about practical example. It is understood that theoretically, the device will not be able to generate stable output that we expect. However, beyond this the details are unknown.

Comment: (I expect buck, too low & boost, too high: follow input with low drop out. Above absolute maximum ratings, I fully expect reduced serviceable life, if not component failure.)

Comment: Above: One common result is that it breaks, with or without smoke, possibly not straight away but maybe it doesn't last as long as it should. Below: probably the output voltage is too low, and it may fluctuate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends how much the input voltage deviates from the nominal range the whole circuit including the external components is designed for.

The chip has to work within the limits set in the data sheet. And there are several limits, including min/max input voltage, min/max duty cycle, max current limit, frequency if it is variable, and if the chip can switch between different modes of operation based on requirements, like pulse skipping.

For too low voltages, undervoltage lockout mechanism keeps the chip off, so for buck regulator, no output, and for boost, there is just diode and inductor from input to output.

If chips are on, they have duty cycle limits, and duty cycle determines relation between input and output voltages.

Buck regulator may have max 100% so it does not switch and output equals input and is too low. Usually buck regulators have minimum on time which limits the minimum duty so with too high input voltages, it can't provide so low duty that is required to produce low enough output voltage, especially if the inductor value is not high enough to allow that long on time that the high input voltage requires.

Also with lower input voltage than nominal, more current is needed to power the required output. Current needed may be too high and regulator can't provide output. The input voltage might sag under high current and the regulator may shut down and restart periodically.

Answer (score 2):

A few things could happen. My guess is the switch might exceed its voltage or current rating. It could saturate the inductor quicker. But above all things will heat up and that isn't good either.